# what is matchDateTimeComponents object in flutter local notification?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

i am using flutter local notification library.

**what is the difference between:**

```
matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime
```

**and**

```
 matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime
```

This shows the notification and repeat every week (same day of week and time).

```
matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time
```

This shows the notification and repeat every day at the same time.

Comment: What do I need to use if I would like to see the notification for e.g. each monday, tuesday, wednesday but not thursday, friday, saturday and sunday? Any ideas? First notification is shown, but the week after it is not.